# PHP word not replace text in doc

Tags: php, laravel, ms-word, phpword

I am trying to make a replacement in a .docx document

```php
public function replace($seach, $replace)
{
    $file = base_path() . '/public/templates/test.docx';

    $phpword = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($file);

    $phpword->setValue('%name%', 'Santosh');
    $phpword->setValue('{lastname}', 'Achari');
    $phpword->setValue('{name}', 'Achari');
    $phpword->setValue('{officeAddress}', 'Yahoo');

    $phpword->saveAs('edited.docx');
}
```

This code replace in `{ }`, but not replace for `%%`

Comment: is it meant to replace for the first option? it looks like the other three are what have become standard placeholders in many templating systems, is it possible its a configurable setting in phpword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation page about [Template processing](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html) the { } brackets are indeed the default, and looking at the [code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/6e4f18c2b0b3064bf59684991daceb2ec8c73ee5/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php#L307) for the `setValue` function no way seems to be built-in to use a different prefix and suffix.

This [issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1022) shows one possible way, but it requires modifying the source of the PHPWord package itself.